# Where should I store lists or maps of objects

Tags: java, oop, conventions

In my project I have several objects like *layouts, groups, boxes and many others*. These objects need to be stored in a list or map with methods to get, remove and put them into the collection. I am currently using static methods and variables in the associated class, for example I have:

```
public class Layout {
    private static Map<String, Layout> layouts = new HashMap<String, Layout>();
    /*
    Other, non-static variables
     */

    public static void addLayout(String name, Layout layout) {
        layouts.put(name, layout);
    }

    public static Layout getLayout(String name) {
        return layouts.get(name);
    }

    public static void removeLayout(String name) {
        layouts.remove(name);
    }

    /*
    Non-static methods for layout
     */
}
```

Would it be better to have a separate class that holds the collection of each kind of object or a single class to hold collections of all the objects? If so, what kinds of names would you use for these classes?

Comment: It's really impossible to say without knowing more about your application. You need to learn more about OO design...

Comment: why are you using static?

Comment: Definitly a chance for you to learn about OO design, play with it and see what you come up with. You will likely learn something good in the process. Also if you were to make a class that had that map some names would be `LayoutManager`, `LayoutConfiguration`, `LayoutFactory` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Just some thoughts. The name should reflect what that class does, given I have no idea what a `Layout` is then its hard to say.

Comment: @ScaryWombat It would be pointless not using static as I need to be able to get a layout without already having an instance of a layout.

Comment: how about having a factory class then?

Comment: @ScaryWombat It's not really a factory, it is more a "container" of layout objects.

Comment: see comments from djechlin and @ug_

Comment: Think about it this way, generally if your doing something that is using static variables and methods that seems like it could or should not be static then your software design is not in good shape. Consider reworking some of your other classes to allow for a `LayoutManger`, `LayoutFactory`... ect to be passed around when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good point of your solution is that you have all belonging to Layout in one class, no more dependencies needed. But using static methods will make it hard to test implementations using that static methods. I won't use one class to hold all, that would create a dependency magnet.

A better approach may be to create repositories for each of the classes like LayoutRepository for storing and retrieving Layouts. Best to use with dependency injection implemented by a container like Spring if your application becomes bigger.

The most simple would be a generic implementation:

```
public class Repository<E> {

  private final ConcurrentMap<String,E> elements = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public void add(String name, E element) {
    elements.put(name, element);
  }

  public E get(String name) {
    return elements.get(name);
  }

  public void remove(String name) {
    elements.remove(name);
  }
}
```

So you have the implementation of the repository separated from the class to store. You can simply reimplement the functionality using a file or database without touching the code using it.

For unit tests you can simply mock the repository to make sure it is used right.

If the creation of the class e.g. Layout have to ensure a valid state, a builder would be a good improvement. Another option is to use a factory to have control over creation of instances. Both should be placed in the same package as the element class and the constructor than must no longer be public.